# How to find the pointwise limit

Tags: limits, functions, pointwise-convergence

I'm having doubts about the pointwise limit of the following function: $f_n(x)=(\tan(x))^n$ with $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}4]$

I know that $f_n$ converges to $0$ when $x∈ [0,\frac{\pi}4[$. However, when $x=\frac{\pi}4$, $f_n$ converges to 1. So it seems that $f_n$ converges pointwise to

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0\mbox{ if $0\leq x<\pi/4$,}\\
1\mbox{ if $x=\pi/4$.}
\end{cases}$$
So because my $f(x)$ isn't continuous i'm not sure what the pointwise limit is.

I'm then going to need to calculate my $M_n$, which is the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, but because I'm not understanding the pointwise limit i don't know what to substitute $f(x)$ for or what the interval of $x$ related to the supremum is.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: As pointed out by Robert Z, don't mess up with uniform continuity. Recall the def: "$f$ is the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ iff $\forall x \in [0,\pi/4], \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n\geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$”. Or simply, $\forall x \in [0,\pi/4],$ $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$.

Comment: Yeah I think I got that, my problem now is choosing the interval in which to check for uniform convergence

Comment: I don't understand. So are you checking that if the sequence of function is uniform convergent on $[0, \pi/4)$? The answer is no :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise limit $f$ is correct. Since $f$ is not continuous, it follows that $(f_n)_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ in $[0,\pi/4]$ (actually neither in $[0,\pi/4)$). What about the uniform convergence in the interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<\pi/4$?

Comment: Ok, so being the pointwise limit the f(x) function, should I choose the first interval 0≤x<π/4 to look for uniform convergence? If so, if in another problem the f(x) is say f(x)={0 if 0≤x≤π/4,1 if π/4<x<5} (just a random example) should I check for uniform convergence on both intervals?

Comment: @A.C In your exercise what is precisely the question about uniform convergence?

Comment: To show that a sequence of function converges pointwise, it is good enough to go from it's def…don't think of uniform convergence first. Pointwise convergence is easier to prove than uniform convergence anyway.

Comment: And Robert actually meant that if the continuous sequence converged uniformly on $[0,\pi/4]$, then the limit would be continuous and contradict the fact that the limit is actually discontinuous.

Comment: Got it! I wasn't aware that the limit not being continuous meant that there was no uniform convergence, it makes sense though. Thank you both! :)